# Why can't i add a new slide to my pure css slideshow?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

This is my code, when i run it with 5 images it works fine. Now when i add a 6th images it doesnt work anymore. It is somehow showing the images in the 1st slide or with bigger images on the 5th slide. Tried many things can't figure it out. I thougth it was the float but that isn't it so i don't know anymore. The arrows arrent showing up so i used white boxes :).

This is my css and html:

```css
.sp-slideshow {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 65%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 260px;
    height: 60%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sp-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.sp-slideshow input {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    z-index: 1001;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

.sp-slideshow input+label {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color linear 0.1s;
}

.sp-slideshow input:checked+label {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.sp-selector-1,
.button-label-1 {
    margin-left: -36px;
}

.sp-selector-2,
.button-label-2 {
    margin-left: -18px;
}

.sp-selector-4,
.button-label-4 {
    margin-left: 18px;
}

.sp-selector-5,
.button-label-5 {
    margin-left: 36px;
}

.sp-selector-6,
.button-label-6 {
    margin-left: 54px;
}

.sp-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 28px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: -19px;
    display: none;
    
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: transparent url(arrows.png) no-repeat;
    background-color:white;
    transition: opacity linear 0.3s;
}

.sp-arrow:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.sp-arrow:active {
    margin-top: -18px;
}

.sp-selector-1:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a2,
.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a3,
.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a4,
.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a5,
.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a6 {
    right: 15px;
    display: block;
    background-position: top right;
}

.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a1,
.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a2,
.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a3,
.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a4,
.sp-selector-6:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a5 {
    left: 15px;
    display: block;
    background-position: top left;
}

input.sp-selector-1:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

input.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -100px 0;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

input.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -200px 0;
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

input.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -300px 0;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

input.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -400px 0;
    background-color: lightpink;
}

input.sp-selector-6:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -500px 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.sp-slider {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: left ease-in 0.8s;
}

.sp-slider>li {
    color: #fff;
    width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.sp-slider>li img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

input.sp-selector-1:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: 0;
}

input.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -100%;
}

input.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -200%;
}

input.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -300%;
}

input.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -400%;
}

input.sp-selector-6:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -500%;
}

input.sp-selector-1:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:first-child,
input.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(2),
input.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(3),
input.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(4),
input.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(5),
input.sp-selector-6:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(6) {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="ImageHomePage.css">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <p>Hoi</p>
 <div class="sp-slideshow">

  <input id="button-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="button-1" class="button-label-1"></label>

  <input id="button-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-2" />
  <label for="button-2" class="button-label-2"></label>

  <input id="button-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-3" />
  <label for="button-3" class="button-label-3"></label>

  <input id="button-4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-4" />
  <label for="button-4" class="button-label-4"></label>
  
  <input id="button-5" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-5" />
  <label for="button-5" class="button-label-5"></label>

  <input id="button-6" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-6" />
  <label for="button-6" class="button-label-6"></label>




  <label for="button-1" class="sp-arrow sp-a1"></label>
  <label for="button-2" class="sp-arrow sp-a2"></label>
  <label for="button-3" class="sp-arrow sp-a3"></label>
  <label for="button-4" class="sp-arrow sp-a4"></label>
  <label for="button-5" class="sp-arrow sp-a5"></label>
  <label for="button-6" class="sp-arrow sp-a6"></label>

  <div class="sp-content">
   <ul class="sp-slider clearfix">
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image01" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image02" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image03" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image04" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image05" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image06"/></li>
    
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- sp-content -->

 </div>
 <!-- sp-slideshow -->

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not good practice to copy and paste code that many times as many items you have. Imagine you want to use thousand of items. Would you copy code 1000 times?

Comment: Your copying and pasting caused an error: the last `nth-child(5)` should be `nth-child(6)`.

Comment: Its for a school project and i can only use css and html.

Comment: Mr lister, when i change it to 6th it also doesnt work.

Comment: I also can't help but think that widths like 20% and 500% are tailored to 5 images, and they need to be changed to accommodate 6. However,. FWIW I agree with @ElChupacabra that at this time you should be thinking about a more dynamic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 images  should make container 600%

6 image should be 16.66% each of the container

```
.sp-slider {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 600%;/* ============  6 images of 100% width */
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: left ease-in 0.8s;
}

.sp-slider > li {
  color: #fff;
  width: 16.66%;/* =====!  X6 = 100% width of parent container */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
.sp-slideshow {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 65%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 260px;
    height: 60%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sp-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.sp-slideshow input {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    z-index: 1001;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

.sp-slideshow input+label {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color linear 0.1s;
}

.sp-slideshow input:checked+label {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.sp-selector-1,
.button-label-1 {
    margin-left: -36px;
}

.sp-selector-2,
.button-label-2 {
    margin-left: -18px;
}

.sp-selector-4,
.button-label-4 {
    margin-left: 18px;
}

.sp-selector-5,
.button-label-5 {
    margin-left: 36px;
}

.sp-selector-6,
.button-label-6 {
    margin-left: 54px;
}

.sp-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 28px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: -19px;
    display: none;
    
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: transparent url(arrows.png) no-repeat;
    background-color:white;
    transition: opacity linear 0.3s;
}

.sp-arrow:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.sp-arrow:active {
    margin-top: -18px;
}

.sp-selector-1:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a2,
.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a3,
.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a4,
.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a5,
.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a6 {
    right: 15px;
    display: block;
    background-position: top right;
}

.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a1,
.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a2,
.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a3,
.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a4,
.sp-selector-6:checked~.sp-arrow.sp-a5 {
    left: 15px;
    display: block;
    background-position: top left;
}

input.sp-selector-1:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

input.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -100px 0;
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

input.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -200px 0;
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

input.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -300px 0;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

input.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -400px 0;
    background-color: lightpink;
}

input.sp-selector-6:checked~.sp-content {
    background-position: -500px 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.sp-slider {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 600%;/* ============  6 images of 100% width */
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: left ease-in 0.8s;
}

.sp-slider > li {
  color: #fff;
  width: 16.66%;/* =====!  X6 = 100% width of parent container */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sp-slider>li img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

input.sp-selector-1:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: 0;
}

input.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -100%;
}

input.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -200%;
}

input.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -300%;
}

input.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -400%;
}

input.sp-selector-6:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider {
    left: -500%;
}

input.sp-selector-1:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:first-child,
input.sp-selector-2:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(2),
input.sp-selector-3:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(3),
input.sp-selector-4:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(4),
input.sp-selector-5:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(5),
input.sp-selector-6:checked~.sp-content .sp-slider>li:nth-child(5) {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="ImageHomePage.css">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <p>Hoi</p>
 <div class="sp-slideshow">

  <input id="button-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="button-1" class="button-label-1"></label>

  <input id="button-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-2" />
  <label for="button-2" class="button-label-2"></label>

  <input id="button-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-3" />
  <label for="button-3" class="button-label-3"></label>

  <input id="button-4" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-4" />
  <label for="button-4" class="button-label-4"></label>
  
  <input id="button-5" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-5" />
  <label for="button-5" class="button-label-5"></label>

  <input id="button-6" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-6" />
  <label for="button-6" class="button-label-6"></label>




  <label for="button-1" class="sp-arrow sp-a1"></label>
  <label for="button-2" class="sp-arrow sp-a2"></label>
  <label for="button-3" class="sp-arrow sp-a3"></label>
  <label for="button-4" class="sp-arrow sp-a4"></label>
  <label for="button-5" class="sp-arrow sp-a5"></label>
  <label for="button-6" class="sp-arrow sp-a6"></label>

  <div class="sp-content">
   <ul class="sp-slider clearfix">
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image01" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image02" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image03" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image04" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image05" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.mulierchile.com/random-image/random-image-013.jpg" alt="image06"/></li>
    
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- sp-content -->

 </div>
 <!-- sp-slideshow -->

 </div>
</body>

</html>
```